# Example of hooking a window?

Tags: .net, winapi, c#-2.0, hook

I want to hook another program's window, so I can get when the cursor enters the window. How to do that? I know that it's with SetWindowsHookEx but I can't find an example (even a native one). I'm doing this in C#2.0, but I can use a native dll if there is a way. Hooking the WM_PAINT or some looping method will also do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set a hook on WM_NCHITTEST which is sent whenever the mouse moves over a window. You simply need to get the window handle then call SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CALLWNDPROC. Your CallWndProc hook should look something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
  if( nCode < 0 ) {
    return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam );
  }

  CWPSTRUCT* pCWP = ( CWPSTRUCT* )lParam;

  switch( pCWP -> message ) {
  case WM_NCHITTEST: {
    ...
    return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam );
  }
  default:
    return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam );
  }
}
```

You could also try SetWindowsHookEx with WH_MOUSE.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find a full example of this? Also is it possible in C# directly?

Comment: The documentation for doing it natively is pretty good here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx. I've quite some experience with it so if you have a specific question I can probably answer it. Unfortunately I don't do C# : )

Comment: Good, but this example doesn't contain the full source.

Comment: Why not ? All you need is the module with the hook procedure in then the call to SetWindowsHookEx() which is all documented on that page.

Comment: Btw why not use TrackMouseEvent ?

Comment: Cause the window is 0 pixels large. That's why I'm trying to hook it. Look at my other request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874327/how-to-hook-flash-player-to-get-its-position

Comment: @blez let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1961/discussion-between-mike-and-blez)

Comment: I'm there, just write when you're online.

Comment: It's not possible to create a global hook in .NET without a native DLL. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-net

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use SetWindowsHookEx. You can hook the window by [subclassing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window) it.

If you wanted to install this hook for every window, *then* you might want to reconsider this method, but all the same, EnumWindows would still work fine.

Comment: I guess in that case then, you could inject a DLL?

Comment: Then the antivirus detects it like a virus.